# How to cast parameters in exposed functions cherrypy?

Tags: python, cherrypy

For example I have a exposed function like:

```
@cherrypy.expose
def create_purchase(self, price, amount, description):

    price = float(price)
    amount = int(amount)
    descript = str(description)
```

Is there a way to automatically cast price to float, amount to int, and description to str.  If any of them fail consider it an error.

Answer (score 2):

There's no builtin solution, but cherrypy's [tools](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/extend.html#tools) provide a hook which could suffice.  Here's an [example hook called params](https://bitbucket.org/coady/lupyne/src/b8b8388f1bed92766e0c44e54fdf542baf1c57c2/lupyne/server.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#server.py-137).  Which would be used like this:

```
@cherrypy.expose
@params(price=float, amount=int, description=str)
def create_purchase(self, price, amount, description):
```

And if you're fortunate enough to be writing Python 3-only code, function annotations would provide an even more elegant solution.

**Update**: This has been built-in since version [6.2](https://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/history.html#v6-2-0).

```
@cherrypy.tools.params()
def create_purchase(self, price: float, amount: int, description):
```

Comment: fortunate i be, but pray describe these function annotations that you speak of